# Induction in reverse to prove polynomials have a form $f(z) = w_0(z-w_1) \cdots (z-w_n)$

Tags: complex-analysis, induction

Given $f: \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ s.t. $f(z) = a_nz^n + \cdots + a_1z + a_0$ with non-zero coefficients, I want to prove there are exactly $n+1$ complex numbers with $f(z) = w_0(z-w_1) \cdots (z-w_n)$.

I'm given that:

1. Any nonzero degree polynomial equation with nonzero coefficients has at least one root
2. Any polynomial equation with at least one root $w$ has a form $f(z) = (z-w)g(z)$, where $g$ is a polynomial function with non-zero coefficients of $n-1$ degrees

Is there something like induction done the other way around, i.e., from n to zero? I ask because, if you give me a small $n$ I can do this proof manually repeatedly applying (1) then (2), but doing this for an arbitrary starting $n$ doesn't seem like it would follow the usual induction method, and would instead require something like induction in the opposite direction.

Comment: I apologize for using Spanish. What you are looking for is called 'principio del descenso infinito' in my language. It was extensively used by Fermat and Euler. The principle is that if you suppose that $P(n)$ is true for every natural $n$ and you get that $P(m)$ is also true for some natural $m<n$, then for every natural $n$, $P(n)$ is false. It is equivalent to the induction principle.

Comment: In English it is called [infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent).

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Following the Wikipedia article, it seems this only goes so far as to prove by contradiction that a proposition isn't true for every natural number. Can we apply this to make exactly $n$ factorizations of an arbitrary $n$ degree polynomial?

Comment: Perhaps for your problem seems more natural to use 'standard' induction, because you are to prove that something is true. But, as I said, they are equivalent, so both should work.

Comment: @ajotatxe hm.. I suppose using standard induction, the base case would be that $a_1z + a_0$ has the form $a_1(z-w)$, where $w$ is a root, but I'm having a hard time seeing how we could use normal induction when proposition (2) is of the form: given an $n$ degree polynomial $f$, there is an $n-1$ degree polynomial $g$ with $f(z) = (z-w)g(z)$. It's the shape of this particular proposition that made me think induction in the opposite way (from $n$ to $0$), would maybe work

Comment: The  problem is that zero-degree polynomials have no roots. So the infinite descent should stop at degree 0. And induction should begin at degree 1.

Comment: Anycase, the easiest way to prove Fundamental Algebra Theorem, for me, is using Liouville's.

Comment: @ajotatxe what would be the inductive step, in a standard induction proof?

Comment: Assume the statement for all polynomials of degree $n$ and let $\deg f=n+1$.  Then for some $w_{n+1}, f=(z-w_{n+1})g$, where $\deg g =n$.  By our inductive hypothesis $g$ can be written in the required form, so $f$ can as well.

Comment: @RobertShore that makes sense, and thank you for your other answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the statement were false.  Then there would be some polynomial $f(z)$ with smallest possible degree $n+1, n \geq 1$ where the statement is false.  We know the degree has the form $n+1, n \geq 1$ because any linear polynomial $az+b$ has the form $a(z- (-\frac ba))$.

We know from $(1)$ that $f(z)$ has some root $w_{n+1}$.  Therefore, we know from $(2)$ that $f(z)=(z-w_{n+1})g(z)$, where $\deg g \lt \deg f$.  But since $f$ has the smallest possible degree of any polynomial that *can't* be written in the required form, we know that $g$ *can* be written in the required form.

So $g(z)=w_0(z-w_1) \ldots (z-w_n)$, which means $f(z)=w_0(z-w_1) \ldots (z-w_n)(z-w_{n+1})$.  This contradiction proves that our hypothesis, the existence of $f$ that can't be written in the required form, is false.  That proves the theorem.

Restating this in the form of infinite descent, if $f=(z-w_{n+1})g$ can't be written in the required form, then $g$, which has smaller degree, also can't be written in the required form.  But that means we could create an infinite chain of polynomials with decreasing degrees, which is impossible.

Comment: I won't downvote, but I think that there is no point in reinventing the wheel

Comment: @ajotatxe  how is that argument reinventing the wheel?  I agree with your comment above that a more direct induction argument is more natural, but the argument presented here is valid too. Nevertheless, the premise for doing the argument this way is only due to the OP's mistake in thinking the result can't be proved by standard induction.